# What kind of error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString is this?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, struts

I got some error from Struts based project in my Eclipse

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString
```

What kind of error is this can any one explain it?

Comment: Please add what jars you have in your project, or post the relevant part of your maven pom file.

Comment: You're missing the Bouncy Castle dependency, just like the error says.

Comment: i already added bouncy Castle dependency in my build path but still i got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file are you looking is from [The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)

> Legion of the Bouncy Castle Java Cryptography APIs
>   Description:
>
> The Bouncy Castle Crypto package is a Java implementation of cryptographic algorithms. The package is organised so that it contains a light-weight API suitable for use in any environment (including the newly released J2ME) with the additional infrastructure to conform the algorithms to the JCE framework.

The file is also downloadable from maven repository [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/140/bcprov-jdk15-140.jar).

You have error because this file is not available in the Java classpath. Download the file and put it into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: but when i am adding bcprov-jdk15-140.jar file then it had given me another new errors like..
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError   
"org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive"

Comment: @NitinKotadiya: Then why have you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't `org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString`, it's [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html). It means that the `org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString` class couldn't be found in any of the directories or jars in your CLASSPATH. From the linked docs:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

Comment: but when i am adding bcprov-jdk15-140.jar file then it had given me another new errors like..
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError   
"org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive"

Comment: @NitinKotadiya: It's still a problem with your CLASSPATH.